Background blur/removal for webcam for Windows 7, OpenCL <= 1.1 and OpenGL <= 4.0
I'm looking for a program for Microsoft Windows 7, OpenCL <= 1.1, and OpenGL <= 4.0 (or doesn't require OpenCL/OpenGL) that can remove or blur the background on my webcam.

What I have found so far:

https://www.chromacam.com requires OpenCL 1.2.
https://snapcamera.snapchat.com/ is unstable on my computer as snapcamera uses OpenGL 4.1.
https://www.xsplit.com/vcam is Windows 10 only (I tried on Windows 7 and it doesn't work).



License: any
Price: any

